# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "order" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to make API orders. The problem appears when I want to display all orders from the database using the GET method, but I get a 500 error and a message

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "order" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"
```

**order.schemas.ts**

```
@Schema()
export class Order {

    @Prop()
    username: string;

    @Prop()
    phone: string;

    @Prop()
    email: string;

    @Prop()
    adr: string;

    @Prop({type: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}]})
    products_id: Product[];

}
```

**product.schema.ts**

```
@Schema()
export class Product {
    @Prop()
    name: string;

    @Prop()
    catalog_number: string;

    @Prop()
    old_price: number;

    @Prop()
    price: number;

    @Prop()
    desc_text: string;

    @Prop()
    desc_short: string;

    @Prop()
    image: string;

    @Prop({type: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Order'}]})
    orders: Order[];
}
```

This is file **order.controller**

```
@Controller('/order')
export class OrderController {
    constructor(private orderServise: OrderService) {   }
    @Post()
    create_order(@Body() dto: CreateOrderDto) {
        return this.orderServise.create_order(dto);
    }
    @Get()
    get_All() {
        return this.orderServise.get_All();
    }
    @Get(':id')
    getOne(@Param('id') id: ObjectId) {
        return this.orderServise.getOne(id);
    }
    @Delete(':id')
    delete(@Param('id') id: ObjectId) {
        return this.orderServise.delete(id);
    }
}
```

This is file **order.service**

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderService {

    constructor(@InjectModel(Product.name) private productModule: Model<ProductDocument>,
                @InjectModel(Order.name) private orderModule: Model<OrderDocument>) {}

    async create_order (dto: CreateOrderDto): Promise<Order> {
        const order = await this.orderModule.create({...dto });
        return order;

    }
    async get_All(): Promise<Order[]> {
        const order = await this.orderModule.find()
        return order;
    }
    async getOne(id: ObjectId): Promise<Order>{
        const order = await this.orderModule.findById(id).populate('products_id');
        return order;
    }
    async delete(id: ObjectId): Promise<Order>{
        const order = await this.orderModule.findOneAndDelete(id);
        return order._id;
    }
}
```

Что может быть не так? Потратил кучу времени на это!

Comment: What version of mongoose do you use? Do you have `mongoose-autopopulate` plugin installed?

Comment: "mongoose": "^6.5.2", mongoose-autopopulate don't installing. Need install?

Comment: Only if you want your relations to be populated automatically. Also I recommend you delete ‘products_id’ property from the orders schema and try running your query without it to verify your schema.

Comment: I did't understand where need to remove the product_id? It is not in the order.schema file.

Comment: Remove this `@Prop({type: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}]})
    products_id: Product[];` from the Schema of orders and try running your query once again to see if it works properly.

Comment: I delete this code, send a request to add an Order, and it was created (it was created before). After trying to send a request to get all orders, but got the same error! What's next?

Comment: Could you share the code of the order creation function? Maybe you have corrupted data in your collection of orders as well. Please edit your post to provide more info about the flow and model definitions.

Comment: Update post! If need I can create zip file and send

Comment: If your `getOne` method works properly and returns the correct document then the only issue I could think of is corrupted data in the collection.

Comment: Yes, `getOne` work fine! If create Order answer Postman like this `{
    "username": "user",
    "phone": "3232-563234-432354",
    "email": "fggsf@dfsd.ru",
    "adr": "test test test",
    "products_id": [
        "62f7b4d84bf8f2cbd334a530",
        "62f7e9c7f5774bb56658424e"
    ],
    "_id": "62f8dfdb4dea24f321f1283c",
    "__v": 0
}`

Comment: And if look product request `{
        "orders": [],
        "_id": "62f7b4d84bf8f2cbd334a530",
        "name": "name",
        "catalog_number": "No.4",
        "old_price": 12100,
        "price": 10285,
        "desc_text": "test",
        "desc_short": "test text",
        "__v": 3
    },`

Comment: In mondoDB account I see this  in Order Table `_id
:
62f8dfdb4dea24f321f1283c
username
:
"user"
phone
:
"3232-563234-432354"
email
:
"fggsf@dfsd.ru"
adr
:
"test test test"
products_id
:
Array
0
:
62f7b4d84bf8f2cbd334a530
1
:
62f7e9c7f5774bb56658424e
__v
:
0`